# Is there a way to preview where an element will be when rearranging Nodes via Drag and Drop in a devexpress TreeListControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, devexpress

I am using a DevExpress 15.2 TreeListControl that allows the user to rearrange nodes by dragging and dropping. This works well, but it's not always clear where the node will be inserted. Is there a way to give the user a preview of the target, similar to the line in Windows Explorers TreeView?

Comment: Maybe you need to set `DataViewBase.ShowTargetInfoInDragDropHint` property to see a hint about the drop target.

Comment: @muaz Unfortunatly this is not supported in the version of DevExpress we are using and i fear updating is not an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In DevExpress 15 the Nodes have a `ShowDropMarker` property you have to set to true.